# Verify hidden text presence using Selenium IDE

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

Creating some test cases for a web page using Selenium IDE,I've found this situation: inside a DIV tag (hidden by a CSS) there is a very long text. I'd like to find a solution to automatically check if a very short portion of this text is matching with a string defined by a regular expression (for example: *check*this*).
The original idea is using verifyTextPresent command with glob:*check*this*, but it seems this idea doesn't like because the element is hidden.

I'm thinking also to use a "SEO" trick to change an hidden DIV by CSS to an hidden (or almost) text with a different solution like putting it in a textarea with dimension 1x1 or 0x0...

Any hint to move forward?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
storeVisible ( locator, variableName )
```

Determines if the specified element is visible. An element can be rendered invisible by setting the CSS "visibility" property to "hidden", or the "display" property to "none", either for the element itself or one if its ancestors. This method will fail if the element is not present.

Arguments:

```
    locator - an element locator
    variableName - the name of a variable in which the result is to be stored.
```

Returns:

```
true if the specified element is visible, false otherwise
```

Related Assertions, automatically generated:

```
    assertVisible ( locator )
    assertNotVisible ( locator )
    verifyVisible (locator )
    verifyNotVisible ( locator )
    waitForVisible ( locator )
    waitForNotVisible ( locator )
```

Comment: @ironFritz, check the answer and let me know it will help you or not

Comment: thank you for your reply, but I was looking for something different. Let me try to explain better: I've some text included inside hidden tags, and I would like to grab that text. For Example: <tag style="display:none"> TEXT TO BE GRABBED </tag>, I'd like to store in a variable "TEXT TO BE GRABBED". Thank you

Comment: @IronFritz  Verifyvisible | xpath of your tag | TEXT TO BE GRABBED
 
try verifyvisible command check CSS and find hidden tag but you have to defined xpath of element.
if this answer help you then please accept my answer